# What does it mean by "失敗就懷孕"?

Tags: translation, meaning, slang

I'm reading a web novel, and it states:

```
“大約是失敗就懷孕之類的任務吧……”
```

What does "懷孕" mean or represent in this context?

Comment: More context would be helpful.  What is the passage about?  Is someone trying to have a child? Could 懷孕 be figurative here?

Comment: @ColinMcLarty you can find the novel right here: http://tieba.baidu.com/f?kz=3181880029&pid=54224172645

林婉儿轻笑：“猪头，到底什么任务啊？”
东城月嘻嘻笑：“大约是失败就怀孕之类的任务吧……”
我无语：“东城你这颗想怀孕的心真是让无数少男伤透心了，你好歹也是女神级的姑娘啊，一定要多多矜持啊！”
东城月又无赖了：“那人家只好不孕不育了。”
我：“……”

Comment: adorable version of "if failed then [f**ked up](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fucked+up)"

Comment: Reading this type of novel which is erotic & ideal just a waste of time and it will not do any help in Chinese language learning. Baidu Tieba must be one of the worst website for all locals and foreigners since there is no valuable or usable content.

Comment: I might get a little  curious about the place you are from。

Comment: Oh.. this is.. .. YOU PROBABLY SHOULDN'T READ THIS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not judging OP's taste of literature, but stories like this would ruin your grammar.

Now the answer:

Obviously, the conversation is between a group of MMO players.

The part of the story here is 凫水囡囡 (ID of a player) wants to do a "task" 任务 which requires a five player team. So he/she, I assume it's a he but she is also possible as this could easily be that kind of story, added four other players in to the group. Those four are supposedly all females as the story called them MM (a online slang for chicks).

So the part of the lines in question come up after they were added and before 凫水囡囡 tells them why "he" added them. Below are a rough line by line translation:

> 将四个MM一一拉入队伍内，也没有说为什么，顿时一个个都惊奇不已的像是好奇宝宝了(。)
>
> Adding four chicks into the team without any explanation got everybody as surprised as curious babies.
>
> 林小舞：“唔，盟主你要对我们做什么，我刚才正帮一秒英雄那小子做一个任务呢！”
>
> Lin Xiao Wu: "Oh, chief/boss/master, what are you gonna do to us, I was just helping Yi Miao Ying Xiong with a job!"
>
> 凫水囡囡：“肯定是有任务了。”
>
> Fu Shui Nan Nan: "I got a job, of course."
>
> 林婉儿轻笑：“猪头，到底什么任务啊？”
>
> Lin Wan Er smiled: "Pighead, what kind of job?"
>
> 东城月嘻嘻笑：“大约是失败就怀孕之类的任务吧……”
>
> Dong Cheng Yue laughed: "Basically the kind of job that will knock you up if failed"
>
> 我无语：“东城你这颗想怀孕的心真是让无数少男伤透心了，你好歹也是女神级的姑娘啊，一定要多多矜持啊！”
>
> I was speechless. "Dong Cheng Yue, how many boys hearts you wanna break with your obsession with knocking-up (or maybe "getting knocked up", don't really know the character). After all you are a goddess level girl. You ought act more conservatively!"
>
> 东城月又无赖了：“那人家只好不孕不育了。”
>
> Dong Chang Yue become shameless again: "Then, I have to go barren."

As I native speaker, I don't really know what do they mean. But as far as I can tell. The character named Dong Cheng Yue is seen to be horny by "Me", and she seem to always say stuff relating to sex. So the phrase might be literally getting pregnant (suggesting the task is hooking up) or just figuratively (suggesting the task is significant), or maybe a little both.

To me it's just a bunch of MMO players joking around or maybe with some sort of flirtation. Anyway, as far as Chinese the language/culture concerns, 失败就怀孕 isn't really a thing. So you can just try to interpret in anyway you want as if it were written in English.

Answer (score 3):

**之類** = this kind/this type

**就** = clause: if xxx 就 (then) xxx

**失敗** = fail / failure

**懷孕** = pregnant

**任務** = task

the kind of task where failure results in pregnancy = if we fail we're screwed

Answer (score 0):

according to the context:

```
婉儿轻笑：“猪头，到底什么任务啊？” 东城月嘻嘻笑：“大约是失败就怀孕之类的任务吧……”
```

Most of the time, in our concept, 懷孕(pregnant) means one man should take responsibility for one woman, aka marry her.

Thus, this means that "東城月 want to play a joke to some man, and she wants to imply the man she love him."

Comment: this is actually exactly the underline meaning in this story, where the MC is in relationship with that girl's best friend but she often joke or attempt to flirt with the mc when her friend is present (she also likes the mc *aka Harlem story)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe, it is only a joking for 不成功便成仁.

And 仁 has the same pronunciation as 人...